# ReactJS how to use html and JS files in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been reading around and it seems quite tricky to do..

I would like to place one HTML file (which contains JavaScript functions, CSS style, and UI rendering displays/data when a user clicks a button) and two associated JS files (that are referenced in the aforementioned HTML file as `</script>`) in the **public directory** of my `npx create-react-app` project.

I want the html file to be on a specific path in `app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Signup from './components/Signup';

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/about' exact={true} component={About}/>
            <Route path='/signup' exact={true} component={Signup}/>
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i would suggest [vite](https://vitejs.dev). `create-react-app` is an artifact of web development before browsers supported [es modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: My side project is a CRUD web app with user authentication/authorization, I am using ReactJS as the frontend.  Would you still recommend vite for my use case?

Comment: vite provides an exceptional frontend experience

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it further and test it.